# Why do the attributes for 'names' behave differently?

Tags: r, attributes, names

I am new to R and I do some google but I cannot find the answer.

```
var <- 1:2
attr(var,"name")<-'gg'
attr(var,"names")<-'gg'
```

However, when I check the attributes of **var**

```
attributes(var)
$name
[1] "gg"

$names
[1] "gg" NA
```

Why for attributes *names* there is an NA? For var[1]?

I am using **R studio, Version 0.99.491 on ubuntu**

Comment: @baptiste - I think since it's naming a vector, therefore `names(vec)` has `length(vec)`. As in `\`names<-\`(1:6, "gg")`

Comment: `names` is a special* attribute that expects one name for each element of the vector (you can also set it using `names()` function). * special in the sense that is treated specially when you print the vector or its attributes...

Comment: If you had checked `attributes(var)` before you started setting custom ones, you'd see...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When considering a basic, atomic vector like `1:2`, `names` are attached to each individual element. Which means, if you don't give `names` to a particular element, R fills them in with `NA` values. I.e.:

```
var <- 1:2
names(var) <- c("a","b")
var
#   a b 
#   1 2 

var <- 1:2
names(var) <- c("a")
var
#   a <NA> 
#   1    2 

var <- 1:6
names(var) <- c("a","b")
var
#   a    b <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> 
#   1    2    3    4    5    6
```